# It is better to load all the entities at the start of a server

Tags: entity-framework

It is better to load all the entities at the start of a server in memory, play with it and once finished (closing the server) ? or it is fast enough to get the entity, modify it on the fly during any operations and save it back to the DB if we are in a server scenario where the server play with data. What would be the best practice ?

Comment: The answer here is going to be pretty specific to your application. I suggest researching eager vs lazy loading, choose an approach, then profile.

Comment: Well to be honest it is not that specific to my application. A server is a server. I could say a game server but its still a server which mean there may be more than 1000 poeple connected and doing requests for several things such getting data for every actions they take. The idea is to know how i should apply EF in such case scenario knowing i am using EF for this.